# Recoding raw types to generics

Tags: java, model-view-controller, oop

I've got some legacy code that I want to upgrade to generics:

```
    /**
     * Places in this World
     */
  public Map places;

    /**
     * Players watching this World
     */ 
  public Collection players;

    /**
     * A reference to the Adventure using this World
     */
  public Adventure owner;

    /**
     * Create a World.  `a' is a reference to the Frame itself.
     * This reference is used when loading images and sounds.
     *
     * @param a An instance of adventure.
     */
  public World( Adventure a ) {
    places = new HashMap();
    players = new LinkedList();
    owner = a; 
  }
```

My IDE warns me that I have not parametrized the variables `places` and `players` so I should add generics to this code but how? When I add `<>` or `<Place>` to the `places´ object then it says it is not generics so however I do it turns out wrong. Could you tell me how to modernize this part of my code to using generics?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for `places`...

First, add types to `places`.  Assuming each value is a `Place`, and each key is a `String`:

```
public Map<String, Place> places;
```

(You need two types: one for the keys, and one for the values.)

Then, in your constructor, do the same thing.

Like so:

```
public World(Adventure a) {
    places = new HashMap<String, Place>();
    ...
}
```

The other fields are simpler; `LinkedList` and `Collection` should only require one type, and if this is old old code, `Adventure` (being part of that code) wouldn't need any.

Comment: Great, it works. I didn't have to change the Adventure declaration and following your advice for the other objects it's now working without warning. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> When I add `<>` or `<Place>` to the `places` object then it says it is not generics

Since you don't show us the exact code, neither the exact error message, one can only guess... Maybe you added it after `places` (which is syntactically incorrect), or you added only a single generic type parameter to `Map` (which needs two: key and value)?

The correct way is

```
public Map<KeyType, Place> places;
```

where `KeyType` stands for the type of the key you wish to use. Once you change this declaration, you also need to update all other references to the map type, like

```
places = new HashMap<KeyType, Place>();
...
public Map<KeyType, Place> getPlaces() ...
```

and possibly also external calls, e.g. to a setter (if there is one).

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to add the type of the objects you want to put in the Map and in the Collection :

```
public Map<PlaceClass> places;

public Collection<PlayerClass> players;

public World( Adventure a ) {
    places = new HashMap<PlaceClass>();
    players = new LinkedList<PlayerClass>();
    owner = a; 
}
```

Where PlaceClass and PlayerClass are the class names of your Player and Place objects.